# Transferring objects across service provider scopes

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a `CorrelationIdMiddleware` that is inspecting incoming request headers and setting a scoped `CorrelationId` later propagated to all `HttpClients`.

```
public class CorrelationId {
    public string Value { get;set; }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    ...
    services.AddScoped<CorrelationId>();
    ...
}
```

I have run into a use case where I need to create an isolated scope around a section of code, but would like the `CorrelationId` from the scope of the http request to propagate into the isolated scope (The isolated scope has an `HttpClient` which I would like to have the same header attached).

I would like to spawn off a background Task that is created from DI w/ any required dependencies and for any HttpClients to have headers injected via HttpClientFactory plugins.

```
public Controller {

    public Controller(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, CorrelationId correlationId) { ... }

    public IActionResult PostTask() {
        var isolatedScope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();

        var action = () => {
            using(isolatedScope) {
                var backgroundJob = isolatedScope
                    .ServiceProvider
                    .GetRequiredService<IBackgroundJob>();
                backgroundJob.Execute();

                // scopedCorrelationId  =/= correlationId
                // how can i get correlationId to jump scopes?
            }
        };

        return Task.Factory.StartNew(
            action,
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
            TaskScheduler.Default);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to transfer certain objects into the isolated scope? Ideally without having to know the `typeof(object)` i need to transfer.

Comment: Why are you trying to solve it via services anyways? If you get the value in a middleware and you need it in the request, you should use [Http Request Features](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/request-features?view=aspnetcore-2.2). Its basically an arbitrary collection to put a class with values in which can be later retrieved everywhere where you got access to `HttpContext`. A couple of middlewares use that (routing for routing data,endpoint middleware,etc. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.features?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: I'm creating a longrunning background task on a different scheduler. The HttpContext will only be available there up until the http request is disposed.

Comment: Well, then you will have to register it as singleton (and assign it to the caller). But you shouldn't really have the need to create a scoped service within a controller. What benefit were you expecting from it? scoped services get disposed on the end of the request. Maybe make it more clear what you try to accomplish

Comment: The isolatedScope will get disposed when the request ends? I thought it was created detached from the request scope?

Comment: Don't think so, since its not resolved but built. But its in a local variable and you can't use it afterwards anyways. Again, write **what problem you try to solve** instead of **what you think will solve your issue**, since your approach seems just seems the wrong way. Sounds like typical case of [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/392095)

Comment: I updated code to better show the code i'm trying to get to work. The use case I would like to get to work is too tie into an existing scheduling system. For the sake of brevity, the scheduling system is a service that: 1) Will make an enternal http call on a schedule to kick off a scheduled job. 2) Listens for a heartbeat from the job on an endpoint. The "jobs" are usually long running (>5 mins). I'm trying to implement an endpoint on a netcore service that will kick off the background job and also monitor it by sending updates to the scheduling system.

Comment: XY Problem. Spinning background tasks/threads in controller is always the wrong way doing it. Ever thought of using a scheduling library such as quartz.net or hangfire? Also why do you even need the correleation id as a service? you get it in the constructor, which you can pass to the delegate scope as a variable (or pass it as parameter to execute etc.)

Comment: The Scheduling system is using Quartz. I'm not cleared to use hangfire and I don't want to implement my own UI for scheduling tasks given that there is already one available. I need to build the scheduling library. The correlationId doesn't need to be a service, I just need to have it available so that it can be accessed from an HttpClientFactory plugin to inject in into outgoing http requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to transfer objects between the parent scope and the isolated scope.

Information like the `CorrelationId` arriving with the headers of a request better fits with the `HttpContext` or with an `AsyncLocal` variable if it needs to be propagated through an async execution flow.